# firebase auth coudn't get user id

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

The following activity crashes when user logged out. It says that FirebaseAuth  is null. I coudn't get the user id. I am using firebase 10.0.1 version.

```
public class CardViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  RecyclerView mContextList;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private Query mQuery;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_card_view);
        mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener(){

            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()==null){
                    Intent loginIntent=new Intent(CardViewActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                    loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(loginIntent);
                }else {

                    startService(new Intent(CardViewActivity.this, Clipboard.class));
                }
            }
        };



        mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Pins");

        mQuery=mDatabase.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        mContextList=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.context_list);
        mContextList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        mContextList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Context,ContextViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Context, ContextViewHolder>(
            Context.class,
            R.layout.context_row,
            ContextViewHolder.class,
                mQuery
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(ContextViewHolder viewHolder, final Context model, int position) {
                final String key=getRef(position).getKey();
               viewHolder.setDate(model.getDate());
                viewHolder.setText(model.getText());
               viewHolder.mView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

                       AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(CardViewActivity.this);

                       // Setting Dialog Title
                       alertDialog.setTitle("Delete..");

                       // Setting Dialog Message
                       alertDialog.setMessage("Do you want to delete the selected context?");

                       // Setting Icon to Dialog


                       // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
                       alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                               // User pressed YES button. Write Logic Here
                               mDatabase.child(key).removeValue();

                              Toast.makeText(CardViewActivity.this,"Deleted!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                           }
                       });

                       // Setting Negative "NO" Button
                       alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                               // User pressed No button. Write Logic Here

                           }
                       });



                       // Showing Alert Message
                       alertDialog.show();
                       return true;
                   }
               });
            }
        };
        mContextList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }

    public static class ContextViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
      View mView;
        public ContextViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
           mView=itemView;

        }
        public void setDate(String date){
            TextView dateTextView=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.context_date);
            dateTextView.setText(date);
        }
        public void setText(String text){
            TextView textTextView=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.context_text);
            textTextView.setText(text);
        }
    }
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        if(item.getItemId()==R.id.action_logout){
            logout();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

    private void logout() {
        stopService(new Intent(this, Clipboard.class));
        mAuth.signOut();
    }
}
```

I am getting following error

```
 07-11 05:37:00.990 3302-3302/com.example.amonc.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.amonc.myapplication, PID: 3302
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.amonc.myapplication/com.example.amonc.myapplication.CardViewActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2572)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference
   at com.example.amonc.myapplication.CardViewActivity.onCreate(CardViewActivity.java:62)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6384)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Comment: Repeating *I need help* three times in your opening paragraph is useless. It's clear you need help or you wouldn't be posting here in the first place. Spend a few minutes reading [ask], and then come back and [edit] your question to **clearly** explain the problem you're having if you want help. While you're making that edit, also change the title so it says something meaningful; all you've done is repeat the tag information, which is useless.

Comment: Help if you can. please

Comment: You've got a NullPointerException. At least explain what you've tried to solve it. If you have no idea start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your user isn't loaded yet when you run this line in `onCreate()`:

```
mQuery=mDatabase.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
```

To ensure a user is loaded, move the code that requires a user into your `onAuthStateChanged()` method:

```
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener(){

        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()==null){
                Intent loginIntent=new Intent(CardViewActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(loginIntent);
            }else {
                startService(new Intent(CardViewActivity.this, Clipboard.class));
                mQuery=mDatabase.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

            }
        }
    };
```

But please read the link Ken provided in the comments, as `NullPointerException`s are quite easy to debug. Just run your app with a debugger attached and Android Studio will break on the source of the problem. The link explains how to continue from there.